# Grails HelpDesk

Tags: grails

So I’m new to grails and I am building a help desk application. The security part will be provided with Spring Security plugin (and Spring Security UI). User will register, log in, go trough few pages of wizard like forms and enter data (subject of incident, description, status, priority, product line, topic, sub-topic, company, contact, etc.). 
If logged as administrator user will have access to  the administrative panel where he will see all incidents in a table, enter any of them, write a response, change status to closed etc.
First question/dilemma is which is the best way to implement the incident wizard? Do I use standard views or Grails flow or something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a business process you want to design. Use a business process management framework for this, e.g. activity, which you can easily use in grails using the plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/activiti

There is a nice sample application, which can be installed via

`grails install-vacation-request-sampleapp`

Once you have installed the plugin and the sample app, you can play around with the sample process. See some screenshots here: http://code.google.com/p/grails-activiti-plugin/wiki/VacationRequestSampleApplication

Comment: Thanks. I agree with you, but I'm not sure how fast and easy can I implement this considering I dont have any experience with BPM systems and in this case Activity. Can you elaborate on this? To be specific I would like to have some basic functionality in week or so and then build on that.

Comment: You can design your process within a few hours. Once this is done, you may need some hours to adjust the GUI. See the example app (I edited my response).